# Não consigo entender esse erro de TypeError : is not a constructor

Tags: javascript

Quando eu clico no botão *salvar* ele realiza o comportamento esperado (cria uma instância de treino, preenche a instância com os `value` do `input` e salva numa lista de instância do objeto `calendario`) e é possivel utilizar o botão *salvar* quantas vezes quiser.

Porém, depois que aperto o botão *mostrar* e tento apertar novamente o *salvar* recebo o erro:

> TypeError: treino is not a constructor

Mas esse erro não deveria ocorrer logo na primeira vez que aperto o *salvar*?

Código:

```js
        class treino {
            treino(dia = "",mes="",ano="",tipo="",url=""){
                this.dia = dia;
                this.mes = mes;
                this.ano = ano;
                this.tipo = tipo;
                this.url = "#";
            }
            
            
            setDados(){
                this.dia = document.getElementsByName("treino-dia")[0].value;
                this.mes = document.getElementsByName("treino-mes")[0].value;
                this.ano = document.getElementsByName("treino-ano")[0].value;
                this.tipo = document.getElementsByName("treino-tipo")[0].value;
                this.url = "#";
            }
            
            mostrar(){
                return `${this.dia}\/${this.mes}\/${this.ano}\ntipo: ${this.tipo}\nurl: ${this.url}`;
            }
        }

        class calendario {
            constructor(){
                this.lista = [];
            }
            
            add(treino){
                this.lista.push(treino);
            }
            
            mostrar(){
                for(treino of this.lista){
                console.log(treino.mostrar());
                }
            }

        }

        function salvar(){
            let t = new treino();
            t.setDados();
            c.add(t);
            console.log(c);
        }

        function mostrarCa(){
            c.mostrar();
        }
        let c = new calendario();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Classes e instancias</title>
</head>
<body translate="no">
    <h1>Registrar Treino</h1>
    <input type="number" max="31" min="1" name="treino-dia" placeholder="Dia" value="1">
    <input type="number" max="12" min="1" name="treino-mes" placeholder="Mês" value="1">
    <input type="number" min="2020" name="treino-ano" placeholder="Ano" value="1">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="treino-tipo" placeholder="Treino" value="treino">
    <button onclick="salvar()">Salvar</button>
    <button onclick="mostrarCa()">Mostrar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro está em seu laço, dentro do método mostrar:

```
mostrar(){
  for(treino of this.lista){
    console.log(treino.mostrar());
  }
}
```

Repare que em seu laço, você não declara a variável treino, e isso acaba gerando seus erros, para corrigir basta declarar a variável treino, com `var`, `let` ou `const`:

```
mostrar(){
  for(const treino of this.lista){
    console.log(treino.mostrar());
  }
}
```

Como você não vai alterar essa variável, é muito comum ela ser declarada como `const`, alguns *lints* inclusive verificam isso.

> Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: Apesar de realmente faltar a declaração de variável, infelizmente não foi o suficiente para resolver.
Para ser mais preciso o erro de código ocorre na linha 
let t = new treino();
Após apertar o botão mostrar. Antes disso ele funciona normalmente.

Comment: Não corrigiu? E que erro passou a ser apresentado após a declaração da variável? Eu testei e a declaração resolveu o problema: https://repl.it/repls/HomelyLikelyVirtualmemory